# comparision not working for file_get_content value

Tags: php, string

**I have a file with content** 
1
2
3

```
<?php
        $input=file_get_contents('/home/abhishek/Desktop/input');
        echo $input ;// i get 1 2 3 as output
        $x='1 2 3';
        if(trim($input)==trim($x))
          echo "hellllliff--";
        else
          echo "helllllelse";
?>
```

**why it goes to else????**

Comment: `var_dump($input);var_dump($x);` then *think*

Answer (score 1):

The new line characters need to be removed - trim would only trim whitespace, not the \n \r characters.

```
preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$input);
```

Would get rid of them if that's the intention. Or alter your comparison string to have new lines too (although watch out for the unix versus pc variance in the new line character)

Comment: Just `str_replace("\n", "", $input);` would do the job.

Comment: Depends on the OS - on windows just \n is often not enough.

Answer (score 0):

1
2
3 in three lines is not equals to

1 2 3 in one line

so it's get false, when compare.For further explaination,$input = 1/n2/n3

Comment: <?php
        $input=file_get_contents('/home/abhishek/Desktop/input');
        echo $input ;// i get 1 2 3 as output
        $x="1\n2\n3\n";
        if(trim($input)==trim($x))
          echo "hellllliff--";
        else
          echo "helllllelse";
?>
but it didnt work